# Is "sooty" natural as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

> The front doors of the burning building opened and a **sooty** Frank
> came out carrying his injured girlfriend in his arms.

1. Is "sooty" the natural choice of word here?
2. Is it okay to say that someone is "sooty" or would it be way more natural to say that someone is covered in soot?

Comment: Or 'soot-streaked'. Soot isn't encountered much these days and 'sooty' might be considered a pejorative term.

Comment: 'Sooty' is OK to describe someone begrimed with soot, where the intended meaning is obvious.

Comment: I am old enough to remember [a little bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sooty)

Comment: I think maybe Jim Davidson has put 'chalky' out of bounds.

Comment: Of course: He walked out of the fire that had been put out and he was all sooty. It's fine. It is not pejorative. "Look at the barbecue grate. It is all sooty." So, a sooty Frank came out is fine.

Comment: @Lambie perhaps you would like it to be removed from this [List of ethnic slurs](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_ethnic_slurs) and others.

Comment: @WeatherVane It depends on context. In the context of a fire, it is not an "ethnic slur". I disagree with much of what the PC establishment claims. It would be a slur to say: "Why you sooty SOB", **for example**. The PC sword must be handled with care.

Comment: @Lambie yes, but, a fire grate *isn't* the OP's context: it is 'sooty Frank' which needs to be handled with care. And SOB is pejorative with or without 'sooty'.

Comment: "The front doors of the ***burning building opened*** and a sooty Frank came." Why do you do this? I just do not get it. A burning building can produce soot, and there is no way a sooty Frank here is pejorative. I gave the example: "sooty SOB" to show a slur.

Comment: What is the source of the quotation here, please?

Answer (score 2):

"sooty" is a perfectly natural way to indicate that someone is covered in soot, or stained with soot, as from a fire. It could also be applied to the walls or other objects.

In the supplied quotation that seems to be the sense used (please provide a source, by the way.)

Soot is rather less common than it was when wood or coal fires were a usual means of heating a building.

However, 'sooty" has been used to refer to a person's natural complexion, when that is black or brown.  In that use it is an ethnic slur, and is also an outdated usage.

Comment: People with fireplaces know all about soot. In fact, you have to have your chimney cleaned every so often to rid it of soot and creosote.

Comment: @Lambie, quite true, but there are rather fewer people with **working** and routinely used fireplaces than there once were, at least in many places, particularly urban areas. And if a fireplace is properly and regularly cleaned, the householder may not routinely encounter much soot.

Comment: Yes, I know that but the adjective sooty can be used there and in the OP's question with no problem.

Comment: When I was a kid in the 1950s, in London, 'sooty' was a pejorative noun.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Are you saying that, in London of the 1950s, "sooty" could not properly have been used to describe a person or object stained with soot in the aftermath of a fire?

Comment: @DavidSiegel - I wrote 'noun'. I meant that a racist might use 'sooty' as a noun like the N-word.

Comment: The fact that we are discussing what a racist might hypothetically say and the only evidence we have is racists from 60 years ago says a lot about racism. The OP’s usage of the adjective is fine. No one will raise an eyebrow.